# refer to a path in root of Django project from a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this structure:

- Project

  - common Application

    - templates

      - common

        - index.html
    - static

      - ...
  - app1 Application

    - ...
  - app2 Application

    - ...
  - ...
  - node_modules

    - swiper

      - swiper-bundle.min.css

I have written this code in index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
```

But it's not working and the swiper-bundle.min.css file is not found.

So, if I use this path `href="/static/swiper-bundle.min.css"` and the `swiper-bundle.min.css` stores in `root/common/static` it will work truly.

How can I access the swiper-bundle.min.css which is located in `root/node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `settings.py` have add:

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'productionfiles'

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'node_modules'
]
```

And the final code in the `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css' %}">
```